# Automated Deployment of Large Numbers of Facebook tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a project for a client who have several hundred retail locations nationwide.  Each of their stores has its own facebook page, and they would like an application that would allow for the automated deployment of Facebook Tabs to these pages - I've looked at the "Impersonation" / manage_pages features of the Open Graph API but can't tell if these would permit tabs to be added to pages remotely.

Are there any other techniques out there that would allow for the automated deployment of tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's technically against the ToS, I'd probably automate that with something like one of the Javascript unittesting frameworks like Selenium.